# Translating from string resources when dynamic content is involved?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I recently figured out how to do localization in MVC using resource files containing strings. Kind of cool that MVC automatically picks the resource file for the visitor's language. I like that!

However, how would I typically handle converting the following message into usage of a resource file?

```
<p>You have @ViewBag.UnreadCount unread e-mails in your inbox</p>
```

As you can see, ViewBag.UnreadCount is a dynamic variable that needs to be included.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [custom helpers](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC---Localization.aspx) taking parameters and use placeholders in your resource files which will be replaced with the dynamic values:

```
<p>@Html.Resource("ResourceName", ViewBag.UnreadCount)</p>
```

P.S. I hope that this `ViewBag` that you have shown here is only for illustration purposes and that in your actual application you are using strongly typed view models.

Comment: Interesting! Very interesting!

Answer (score 3):

I just use `string.Format` with my resource file.

I haven't tried it with MVC, but it should still work

```
@(string.Format(YourResourceFile.Resource, ViewBag.UnreadCount))
```

And in your resource file

```
You have {0} unread e-mails in your inbox
```

Not exactly the most intuitive method, but it does the job just fine. I'll just use the comment field in the resource file to explain to the translator what the parameters are going to be.

Comment: I had feared that would be the solution. I'll wait a few days and see if better results dump in. Then I'll mark this as answer if not.

Answer (score 1):

The best way of doing this is using, `string.Format(Resource.UnreadCount ,ViewBag.UnreadCount)` and resource string will be like "there are {0} unread counts".

There is a blog talk more about [localization](https://kevww.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/the-problems-of-model-metadata-and-validation-localization-in-mvc/)

*EDIT: The blog linked above belongs to the author of this answer.*

Comment: Please see the site FAQ. You *must* disclose that the blog you have linked to here is yours..

Comment: Really? That's an odd rule. You'd expect any public blog would love extra traffic. I voted it up. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen Here's a direct quote from the [Stack Overflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) "Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers." Emphasis is *in the original*; I did not add it.

Comment: sorry I am recently inspired to answer questions. Trying to help others. Not realize there are certain rules out there.